# Generate a range of numbers in Apache Derby

Tags: sql, range, derby

Is there a way to generate a range of numbers (eg. 21000 - 23500) using only SQL in Apache Derby?

Below is my dodgy hack. Is there a better way?

```
select num from
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as num
    from SYS.SYSCOLUMNS
    join SYS.SYSCOLUMNS
        on true
    join SYS.SYSCOLUMNS
        on true
) tmp
where num between 21000 and 23500
```

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? Or do you have an underlying problem you're trying to solve? There are so many other ways to generate a range of integers in a computer program that it's hard to imagine what use you're going to put this technique to.

Comment: Hi Bryan, it's not just an academic exercise. Indeed it's easy to generate numbers in programming languages, but some users sometimes only have access to a database client and can only execute sql. Other times one might want to put together a single script to update a database (which is my case). This same question has been asked on SO for MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server to name a few.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the follow-up. If I was doing this for real myself using Derby, I'd write a Derby system procedure that could generate a result set containing integers in the specified range, and then my SQL would simply invoke that system procedure. But it sounds like you're trying to do something different. On the chance that writing a Derby system procedure would work for you, look here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevspecialtfbasic.html

Comment: Nice one, thanks Bryan. I'll look into that